# enable button if value in textfield 1 is greater than textfield 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project and what i want to achieve is when the value is textfield2 is lesser than the value in textfield1, the button must be enabled and i know jquery or javascript will be needed to make this happen

```
<table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
   <tr>
      <td width="89" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 1
         <div align="left"></div><label></label>
      </td>
      <td width="291" align="center" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext"><div align="left">
            <input name="Textfield1" type="text" class="textbox" id="Textfield1" placeholder="Enter Amount" autocomplete="off" value="10">
            <div></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 2</td>
       <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext"><label for="Textfield2"></label>
            <input name="Textfield2" type="password" class="textbox" id="Textfield2" placeholder="Enter your Password">
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right" class="redtext"><button disabled>Submit</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

any help?

Comment: Have you tried achieving this yourself yet? If so, please post your attempted JS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `keyup` to identify changes on the `input`

*`parseFloat` parses a string argument and returns a floating point number*

*`.prop()` set one or more properties for every matched element*

Try this:

```js
$('#Textfield1,#Textfield2').on('keyup', function() {
  var btn = $('button.mybutton');
  if (parseFloat($('#Textfield1').val()) > parseFloat($('#Textfield2').val())) {
    btn.prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    btn.prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
  <tr>
    <td width="89" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 1
      <div align="left"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="291" align="center" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext">
      <div align="left">
        <input name="Textfield1" type="text" class="textbox" id="Textfield1" placeholder="Enter Amount" autocomplete="off" value="10">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 2</td>
    <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext">
      <label for="Textfield2"></label>
      <input name="Textfield2" type="password" class="textbox" id="Textfield2" placeholder="Enter your Password">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" class="redtext">
      <button disabled class='mybutton'>Submit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9bzoz3d2/)

Comment: what if the button comes with a class? for example class="mybutton" . how is the script going to be

Answer (score 0):

```
function enableBtn(){
      textBox1 = parseFloat($("#Textfield1").val());
      textBox2 = parseFloat($("#Textfield2").val());
      if(textBox1 > textBox2)
      {
         $(".redtext button").prop("disabled", false); 
      }else{
         $(".redtext button").prop("disabled", false); 
      }
}

$('#Textfield2, #Textfield1').on('input',function(e){
   enableBtn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jameshwartlopez/re18vj9h/1/)

```js
$('#Textfield2, #Textfield1').on('keypress',function(){
   var text1 = parseInt($('#Textfield1').val());
   var text2 = parseInt($('#Textfield2').val());

   var btn = $('.redtext > button');
   if(text1 > text2){
     btn.prop('disabled', false);
   }else{
      btn.prop('disabled', true);
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
        <tr>
          <td width="89" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 1
            <div align="left"></div>
            </label></td>
          <td width="291" align="center" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext"><div align="left">
            <input name="Textfield1" type="text" class="textbox" id="Textfield1" placeholder="Enter Amount" autocomplete="off" value="10">
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 2</td>
          <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext"><label for="Textfield2"></label>
            <input name="Textfield2" type="password" class="textbox" id="Textfield2" placeholder="Enter your Password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="right" class="redtext"><button disabled>Submit</button></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
    <table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
        <tr>
          <td width="89" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 1
            <div align="left"></div>
            </label></td>
          <td width="291" align="center" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext"><div align="left">
            <input name="Textfield1" type="text" class="textbox" id="Textfield1" placeholder="Enter Amount" autocomplete="off" value="10">
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 2</td>
          <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext"><label for="Textfield2"></label>
            <input name="Textfield2" type="text" class="textbox" id="Textfield2" placeholder="Enter your number"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="right" class="redtext"><button disabled class=
"disabledButton">Submit</button></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#Textfield2').keyup(function(){
     var textBox1 = $('#Textfield1').val();
     var textBox2 = $('#Textfield2').val();
     if(textBox2>textBox1){
       $('.disabledButton').prop("disabled", false);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
        <tr>
          <td width="89" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 1
            <div align="left"></div>
            </label></td>
          <td width="291" align="center" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext"><div align="left">
            <input class="amtBox" name="Textfield1" type="text" class="textbox" id="Textfield1" placeholder="Enter Amount" autocomplete="off" value="10">
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="blacktext">Textfield 2</td>
          <td bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="redtext"><label for="Textfield2"></label>
            <input class="amtBox" name="Textfield2" type="text" class="textbox" id="Textfield2" placeholder="Enter Amount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="right" class="redtext"><button id="butSubmit" disabled>Submit</button></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.amtBox').on('keyup keypress blur', function(){
            var Textfield1 = $('#Textfield1').val();
            var Textfield2 = $('#Textfield2').val();
                console.log(Textfield1 + " :: " + Textfield2);
            if (Textfield2 < Textfield1) {
                $('#butSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
                console.log("Less");
            } else {
                $('#butSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
                console.log("More");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

try this !!